# ¿Cómo mostrar la hora actual dentro de un <p>?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado mostrar la hora en tiempo real dentro de un `<p>`, pero aunque la consola de Firefox no me muestra error, la hora no aparece. Este es el código actual:

```html
<p id="display-time">
    <script>
        function myFunc() {
            var now = new Date();
            var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
            return time;
        }
        myFunc();
        setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
    </script>
</p>
```

He probado varias combinaciones, como incluir `document.write()`, pero me decía que está `undefined`.

¿En qué podría estar fallando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es problema es que no debes hacer un `return` en tu función, sino signar el valor al elemento correspondiente.

```js
function myFunc()  {
 var now = new Date();
 var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
 document.getElementById('display-time').innerHTML= time;
}
myFunc();
setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

```html
HORA: 
<p id="display-time">

</p>
```

> No hace falta que añadas el javascript dentro del elemento HTML, esto
>   puede llevar a confusión, es mejor acostumbrarse a poner en una parte
>   el HTML y en otra el javascript. Para manipular elementos desde
>   javascript es necesario esperar a que el DOM los tenga cargados.

Comment: ¡Solucionado! Gracias, tenía dudas con lo del return.

Answer (score 6):

Pues si, tienes todo correcto, sin embargo a tu `script` le falta enviar la data al [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Tienes algunas alternativas, yo usaré `innerHTML`.

Cuando ejecutas `setInterval()`, le dices que la función `myFunc()` se ejecute cada 1 segundo. Pero la función `myFunc()` si bien calcula el tiempo y lo pone en una variable `time`, la retorna a `setInterval` y no sucede nada. En vez de retornar el valor de `time`, lo que debes hacer es enviarlo al `DOM`. Para eso puedes usar la propiedad `innerHTML` del elemento `<p>`, la cual seteas de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById('display-time').innerHTML = time;
```

Dicho esto, tu código puede quedar así:

```html
<p id="display-time">
<script>
    function myFunc()  {
        var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('display-time').innerHTML = time;
    }
    setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
</script>
</p>
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunc() {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('display-time').innerHTML = time;
}

setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="display-time"></p>
```

Creo que buscabas algo como esto.